# Fixed background with CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to fix my background to 100% height of body and leave it there even when rest of the page scrolls.

How do I achieve this?
Right now all I have is `background:url(bg.png);`. The height of the image is 1200px and width 20px, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want the background image to do there are a couple of options. There is a great article on ALA about full screen BG images that accounts for scaling:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supersize-that-background-please/

If you are just looking to position the image in the browser you would do:

```
background:url(bg.png) no-repeat top left;
background-attachment:fixed;
```

Or however you want to position it respectively (top right, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

in css, use this:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: need to use background-attachment i believe

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers still have trouble supporting the stretching of background images so here's a [workaround](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm).

[CSS3 Example and Support](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_backgrounds.asp)

Since it's already 1200px, you can use `background-attachment:fixed;` on the background to make it follow when they scroll. Example at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position). You can make the image look like it is meant to flow into a solid color at the bottom with a nice gradient, etc.